# Shell searching for a line

Tags: regex, grep

Hello I have simple file called myfile.txt ,in there there are only 3 lines :

```
   192.168.20.30
   text123
   192.168.1.1
```

I am trying to grep all IPs in the form number.number.1 I tried with this regex

```
grep [0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[1] myfile.txt
```

but it prints the 3 lines,any ideas why,it is supposed to print 192.168.1.1 only

Comment: Try with `^` - `grep '^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.1' myfile.txt`

Comment: If the numbers are required change the `*` to a `+`. It looks like the `grep` processes the backslashes when outside quotes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  tried your solution even without ^ at the start it works,so why with ' ' it works ?

Comment: @user271261 I guess because of the backslash.

Comment: Yes, it is the backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the single quotes the shell removes the backslashes from the pattern, it looks as `[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[1]` and it matches 0+ digits, then any char, again 0+ digits, again any char and then `1`.

You must use quotes:

```
grep '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.1' myfile.txt
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/3rdoS3). You may see that `echo [0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[1]` prints `[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[1]` and `echo '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.1'` prints `[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.1`.

Note that you may use `-E` option with `grep` and use `+` quantifier (*1 or more* occurrences): [`grep -E '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.1'`](http://ideone.com/080BWv) (at least, with GNU grep).

Comment: and one more question how can I grep all lines containing unknown times the symbol b for example?

Comment: Excuse me, I do not get this requirement. Just `b` should be enough.

Comment: Then what is the difference between grep 'b' and grep '[b]*'

Comment: @user271261: Please note that `b*` matches *0 or more `b` chars*. It means it also matches an empty string. And every string contains an empty string, `b*` will match any string. `b` will only match a string that contains at least 1 `b`.